# percentage of animal diseases caused by bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, pathology

I know this is a long shot, but what is the approximate percentage out of all the animal diseases that are caused by bacteria? One of the Q&A websites answer it as 90, but is there any conclusive scientific evidence?